# How to import instances of a Class in Python?

Tags: python, class, instance

```
class Tweeter:

    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret_key, bearer_token, access_token, access_token_secret ):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret_key = api_secret_key
        self.bearer_token = bearer_token
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.access_token_secret = access_token_secret

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(self.api_key, self.api_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(self.access_token, self.access_token_secret)

        self.api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

How can I import an instance of a class from the file in which the instance was created to another .py file.

For example: `instance1 = Tweeter(xargument,yargument, zargument)`

How do import and/or call the instance that I created in another file without having to import the detail that clutter up the code.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing `from your_module import instance1`?

Comment: What detail would you import that clutters up the code?

Comment: "How do import and/or call the instance that I created in another file without having to import the detail that clutter up the code." that doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd use parameters to pass around your API client instance, rather than global application imports

You shouldn't need multiple (numbered) instances of it, either.

```
from classes import Tweeter  # for example

if __name__ == "__main__":
  t = Tweeter(...)
  some_function(t, some, other, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from name_of_your_file_that_Tweeter_is_in import Tweeter

from file_x import Tweeter
instance1 = Tweeter(xargument,yargument, zargument)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you initialize your class instance of `Tweeter` outside of a function or method, then you should be able to import that instance. Keep in mind that all the code that is not within a function or class is ran whenever you import from that file. For example:

```
# tweeter.py
Class Tweeter:
    ...


# This code is ran whenever this file is imported from another file
tweeter = Tweeter(<arguments to pass to the __init__ function>)



# my_file.py


from .tweeter import tweeter # Assuming both files are in the same directory

# now you have the same class instance from the tweeter.py file
print(tweeter)
```